# Google Maps - Multiple Markers

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I've been searching all over trying to find simple code to add multiple markers to Google Maps.  I've adjusted code to the simple marker example in hopes that it would work.  I don't get any errors from the php code, so I am guessing the map code is screwed up.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $latlonlocation; ?>);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: <? echo $zoom; ?>,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map
   });

   var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
     map: map,
     radius: <? echo $searchradius; ?>
   });
   circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
<?
$mapcounter = "01";
while ($row106 = mysql_fetch_array($r106)) {
    if ($row106["mna"] == 1 && $row106["mrt"] == 1) {
        $imagecolor = "yellow";
    } elseif ($row106["mna"] == 1 && $row106["mrt"] == 0) {
        $imagecolor = "darkblue";
    } elseif ($row106["mna"] == 0 && $row106["mrt"] == 0) {
        $imagecolor = "red";
    } else {
        $imagecolor = "red";
    }
    $imagenumber = sprintf("%02d",$mapcounter);
    echo "var image = 'mapicons/$imagecolor$imagenumber.png';";
    echo "var DealerMarker$imagenumber = new google.maps.Marker({";
    $lats = $row106["latitude"];
    $lons = $row106["longitude"];
    echo "position: $lats $lons,";
    echo "map: map,";
    echo "icon: image";
    $mapcounter++;
    echo "});";
}
?>

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I've also tried modifying the `});` at the end to have it either inside or outside the array loop.  Neither has worked.  The exact code worked with static variables before I added the array loop to it.  Can anyone get me going in the right direction

Comment: This is a classic RTFM. There's extensive documentation (including full examples) available on the API reference.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing 
`echo "position: $lats $lons,";` 
with `echo "position: new google.maps.LatLng($lats, $lons),"`